# How to Notify a folder using SHChangeNotify

Tags: c++

My application will create some folders and it's icon needs to be changed depending on certain activities.

I tried to use the function below and it seems it's not refreshing the folder

`SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED,  SHCNE_ALLEVENTS | SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE | SHCNE_UPDATEDIR |SHCNF_PATH | SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, L"C:\\Music\\Test", 0);`

If I use
`SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, 0x1000, 0,0);`,
 the entire desktop is getting refreshed.

Please let me know the best way to refresh folders.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using the wrong function. In particular, the documentation for `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED` states that "`SHCNF_IDLIST` must be specified in the `uFlags` parameter. dwItem1 and dwItem2 are not used and must be NULL.". You do not pass `SHCNF_IDLIST` and `dwItem1` is a path string, not `NULL`. Also, the second parameter should be just a combination of `SHCNF_*` flags; you're adding invalid `SHCNE_*` flags.

If you're writing files to `L"C:\\Music\\Test"`, and want Explorer to notice that, use `SHCNE_CREATE`; if you add a folder use `SHCNE_MKDIR`. In both cases, `dwItem1` must be the path to the item created, not the parent folder where it's created in.

Comment: Thanks MSalters, I will do the changes and test it.

Comment: your solution seems working, but i can do the complete testing after finishing the other modules.

Comment: My application is ready for testing now. I treid your suggestion still not working, The new icons are not diplaying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEDIR, SHCNF_PATH | SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, "Path", NULL);
where "Path" is the folder you want to update.